# Sonatype Nexus: How to create Blob stores using Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins, amazon-s3

I try to create a blob stores on Sonatype Nexus as below:

[image: Create Nexus blob stores steps]

Then, I'm getting this error:

[image: Create Nexus blob stores Error]

> Unable to initialize blob store bucket: s3jenkins-cache, Cause: Unable
>   to execute HTTP request: Connect to
>   s3jenkins-cache.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com:443
>   [s3jenkins-cache.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/52.219.56.35] failed:
>   connect timed out

- The access key just working fine.
- Nexus is run on AWS EC2.
- Access key have full permission in AWS S3.
- About network, I can manually push file from Nexus EC2 into S3 repo.

**I wonder what did I miss? Someone has done it. Thanks so much**

Access key has full permission in
   S3.

More Nexus log detail:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP
> request: Connect to
> s3jenkins-cache.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com:443
> [s3jenkins-cache.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/52.219.56.35] failed:
> connect timed out     at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1063)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4247)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4194)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1326)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1266)
>   at
> org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.s3.internal.S3BlobStore.init(S3BlobStore.java:474)
>   ... 106 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to
> s3jenkins-cache.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com:443
> [s3jenkins-cache.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/52.219.56.35] failed:
> connect timed out     at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor754.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
>   at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy244.connect(Unknown Source)    at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1235)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1055)
>   ... 117 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out    at
> java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
>   at
> com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:132)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Nexus (>3.12) S3 integration is in built. You just have to create a policy & a use attaching that policy in AWS & then create S3 bucket. Then add your S3 bucket details in Nexus. Also you can refer to [this detailed guide](https://techeggzone.com/cicd/how-to-create-a-blob-store-in-aws-s3-for-sonatype-nexus/)